# orderBy and sort is not applied on the full dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, palantir-foundry, incremental-build, foundry-code-repositories

The final result is sorted on column *'timestamp'*. I have two scripts which *only* differ in *one* value provided to the column *'record_status'* ('old' vs. 'older'). As data is sorted on column *'timestamp'*, the resulting order should be identic. However, the order is different. It looks like, in the first case, the sort is performed *before* the union, while it's placed after it.

Using `orderBy` instead of `sort` doesn't make any difference.

Why is it happening and how to prevent it? (I use Spark 3.0.2)

**Script1 (full) - result after 4 runs (builds):**

[image]

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Output, incremental
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T


@incremental(
    require_incremental=True,
)
@transform(
    out=Output("ri.foundry.main.dataset.a82be5aa-81f7-45cf-8c59-05912c8ed6c7"),
)
def compute(out, ctx):

    out_schema = T.StructType([
        T.StructField('c1', T.StringType()),
        T.StructField('timestamp', T.TimestampType()),
        T.StructField('record_status', T.StringType()),
    ])
    df_out = (
        out.dataframe('previous', out_schema)
        .withColumn('record_status', F.lit('older'))
    )

    df_upd = (
        ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame([('1',)], ['c1'])
        .withColumn('timestamp', F.current_timestamp())
        .withColumn('record_status', F.lit('new'))
    )

    df = df_out.unionByName(df_upd)
    df = df.sort('timestamp', ascending=False)

    out.set_mode('replace')
    out.write_dataframe(df)
```

**Script2 (full) - result after 4 runs (builds):**

[image]

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Output, incremental
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T


@incremental(
    require_incremental=True,
)
@transform(
    out=Output("ri.foundry.main.dataset.caee8f7a-64b0-4837-b4f3-d5a6d5dedd85"),
)
def compute(out, ctx):

    out_schema = T.StructType([
        T.StructField('c1', T.StringType()),
        T.StructField('timestamp', T.TimestampType()),
        T.StructField('record_status', T.StringType()),
    ])
    df_out = (
        out.dataframe('previous', out_schema)
        .withColumn('record_status', F.lit('old'))
    )

    df_upd = (
        ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame([('1',)], ['c1'])
        .withColumn('timestamp', F.current_timestamp())
        .withColumn('record_status', F.lit('new'))
    )

    df = df_out.unionByName(df_upd)
    df = df.sort('timestamp', ascending=False)

    out.set_mode('replace')
    out.write_dataframe(df)
```

**Query plans** in both transformations show that sorting must be performed after the union (inspecting logical and physical plans I see no differences except for IDs and RIDs, but all the transformation steps are in the same place):

[image]

**Observation:**
Using the following profile the sort works well (query plans don't change):

```
@configure(["KUBERNETES_NO_EXECUTORS_SMALL"])
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got your problem, could you share more? Like the top 5 lines (descending by timestamp) of the input datasets and the line of code you used to print the screenshot you posted?

Comment: This is Palantir Foundry question. Foundry is built on Apache Spark, but it's not the same. I've provided full transformation scripts - nothing was truncated. Only 4 lines exist after 4 builds, so I cannot provide 5 lines (1 build adds 1 line). And the problem is that sorting is supposed to be done by code just before writing results back to the system. I mean, it's not about sorting after results were written.

Comment: Hi ZygD I'm reaching out from Palantir side. We've discussed your question internally and a colleague dug into the the generated query plan, it seems spark is optimizing your transform and doing the sort before the union, even though it comes later in the transform. We don't have a rational for it atm, thus not having a formal answer, but didn't want to leave you idling in silence much longer :)

Comment: Hi, @fmsf. It looks more like the sorting is performed separately in every partition... Please take a look at the answer I came up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, this behavior is not caused by `@incremental`. It can be observed in a regular transformation too:

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Output
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


@transform(
    out=Output("ri.foundry.main.dataset.beea7dd2-8da3-4abf-9103-464ec646dc00"),
)
def compute(out, ctx):

    data = [("1", "2022-02-16T17:48:15.653Z", "older"),
            ("1", "2022-02-16T17:46:58.054Z", "older"),
            ("1", "2022-02-16T17:50:50.850Z", "new")]
    df_inp = (
        ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame(data, ["c1", "timestamp", "record_status"])
        .withColumn("timestamp", F.to_timestamp("timestamp"))
        .withColumn("record_status", F.lit("older"))
    )
    df_upd = (
        ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame([('1',)], ['c1'])
        .withColumn('timestamp', F.current_timestamp())
        .withColumn('record_status', F.lit('new'))
    )

    df = df_inp.unionByName(df_upd)
    df = df.sort(F.desc('timestamp'))

    out.write_dataframe(df)
```

[image: Incorrect sort results using transform decorator without input datasets]

When asking the question, I provided 2 scripts: one containing supposedly working `sort`, the other - failing `sort`. The reality is that both scripts don't work, just the "correct" one needed more runs to start showing incorrect sort order:

[image: Foundry bad sort or groupby order]

**The reason** lies in the partitioning of input dfs. Apparently, `sort` and `groupBy` performs the sort only in partitions (there are several of them). For some reason data is not moved to one executor or driver. Therefore, the resulting combined dataset does not have a unified sort order. This is why the usage of profile "KUBERNETES_NO_EXECUTORS_SMALL" yielded correct sort order (all operations were performed in one node - the driver).

**The only solution** I could find was using `df.coalesce` just before the `df.sort()` line:

```
df = df_out.unionByName(df_upd)
df = df.coalesce(1)
df = df.sort(F.desc('timestamp'))
```

Since Spark 3.2.0, `df = df.repartition(1)` will also work.

Comment: Thanks ZygD, I am here because of the same issue with orderBy in Foundry. One thing I'm not clear on - is this a Foundry specific issue? I have not seen any sort/orderBy docs that specify any info on this.

Comment: @tessa - To me it seems that it's Spark issue. I have run the above code in a clean Spark 3.3.0 shell and I noticed that in the Physical Plan, immediately before the sort line there's *rangepartitioning(...,200)* which may create up to 200 partitions. The sort will not work as we expect if more than 1 partition is created before sorting. Our options currently are `df = df.coalesce(1)` or `df = df.repartition(1)`.